# Multiple images upload to Bucket AWS S3 using swift

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, file-upload

I am tryin to upload an image to bucket AWS s3 using below code.

```
    let ext = "jpeg"
    let uploadRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
    uploadRequest?.acl = .publicRead
    uploadRequest?.body = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    uploadRequest?.key = s3BucketKey
    uploadRequest?.bucket = S3BucketName
    uploadRequest?.contentType = "image/" + ext
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.default).async {
        let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.default()
        transferManager.upload(uploadRequest!).continueWith { (task) -> AnyObject! in
            if let error = task.error {
                print("Upload failed ❌ (\(error))")
            }
            if task.result != nil {
                let s3URL = "http://s3.amazonaws.com/\(S3BucketName)/\(String(describing: uploadRequest!.key!))"
                print("Uploaded to:\n\(s3URL)")
                completion(s3URL)
            }
            else {
                print("Unexpected empty result.")
                completion(nil)
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
```

But now I need to upload multiple images to bucket AWS S3, I thought of using same same function in loop to upload files using but its taking more processing time, also I need to sync my data once all images get uploaded.

Please suggest workaround which will take less processing time to upload multiple images and I should get notified once all images get uploaded. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey any update this task ? I am very interested on this. Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [RxSwift](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift) framework. Something like...

```
// Multiple image uploading
RRAWSRxUpload.upload(dataList: [AWSImageData(type: .image1, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image1")), AWSImageData(type: .image2, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image2"))])
.subscribeOn(ConcurrentDispatchQueueScheduler.init(qos: .background))
.observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
.subscribe(onNext: { response in
    print(response)
    //Get here all file uploaded key names after that you will call your server API call to update those files.
}, onError: { error in
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}).disposed(by: rxbag)
```

Also, find out more detail on GitHub demo of [RRAWSRXUpload](https://github.com/Rahul-Mayani/RRAWSRxUpload).

And you can also call your server API by RxSwift with [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) library.

Once you finished AWS S3 upload part after that you will call your server Alamofire APIs request by [RRAlamofireRxAPI](https://github.com/Rahul-Mayani/RRAlamofireRxAPI).

```
RRAWSRxUpload.upload(dataList: [AWSImageData(type: .image1, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image1")), AWSImageData(type: .image2, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image2"))])
        .flatMap { (keys) -> Observable<DataModelObject> in
            print(keys)// pass your files array/model to your server as parameters
            return RRAPIRxManager.rxCall(apiUrl: APIEndPoint.Name.uploadAWSImage, httpMethod: .post, param: parameters)
        }
        .subscribeOn(RXScheduler.concurrentBackground)
        .observeOn(RXScheduler.main)
        .subscribe(onNext: {(response) in
            print(response)
        }, onError: { (error) in
            print(error)
        }).disposed(by: rxbag)
```